# Brand new 10.10 Yosemite mail.app can not work with Yahoo Mail?

Tags: mail.app, imap, yahoo

As of January 2015, I have a brand new Macbook Air running all fully updated Yosemite 10.10.

I have been simply trying to configure the mac OS mail app to work with a simple, normal Yahoo Mail account.

I add the account, it appears correctly in the Preferences settings as an internet account with "mail" checked... it creates entries in the left pane of the Mail window.   BUT... nothing ever appears in the Inbox.   AND, it DOES succeed in loading the many sub-folders within the mail account that I have configured in yahoo... AND, if I click on one of those, then after 20 seconds, it loads the folder's contents fine. AND, when I SEND mail, it sends out just fine.  But nothing in the normal, plain Inbox!

I have created it several times. Once I even tried to force it to allow me to "manually" create the inbox without it sniffing that it was a yahoo account and applying the official yahoo settings it knows. I did that by initially putting extra false characters in the yahoo domain name, and then setting up all the IMAP and SMTP stuff manually, and then changing the initial domain name entry to remove the wrong characters.  But the results were exactly the same -- empty inbox.

AND, when I have yahoo set up in the normal way (but not working right...)  and I go to the Connection Doctor... it scans through and gives the green-light indicator saying that IMAP and SMTP are working fine!

Any info, tips, or similar issues with Yahoo Mail and the mail.app in Yosemite?

THANKS -- Eric

Comment: One more note. One day later, the problem persists... but I do notice that one NEW email arrived since I set up the account in mail... and that newly arriving email DOES appear in the inbox.   But where are the thousands of previous emails in the inbox!  Seems it won't load the inbox items from prior to the setup of that account in Mail? Only new?   Not really workable. And given it's one of the main email services, and given that Apple has the specifically branded "yahoo" option to configure it... it should work!

Comment: I also had major problems using Mail.app for my sbcglobal (yahoo) account since buying a new computer running Yosemite. When set up as IMAP, the Internet Accounts preferences pane automatically deselected "Mail" when I activated Calendars or another functionality. For now, I have switched to Postbox, but I'm hoping this issue will eventually be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you did all these things, but just in case...

1. Turn POP access in Yahoo mail through browser:
   https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/SLN15404.html?impressions=true
2. Check you IMAP settings in Mail app:
   https://help.yahoo.com/kb/imap-server-settings-yahoo-mail-sln4075.html
3. Check that you actually do have messages in your Inbox (through browser) :)
4. Check that you do not have Forwarding ON:
   https://help.yahoo.com/kb/automatically-forward-emails-yahoo-mail-sln22028.html

If this didn't help, let's search further...

Comment: FYI: I just have added Yahoo account to my mail app and it does work as expected. Yosemite 10.10.3 on MBP

Answer (score 0):

Open the Mail.app then click mailboxes, then click sync mailbox.

Comment: Yep, tried this... stays in the same situation -- even the subfolders are getting contents, but the inbox itself remains empty (or, weirdly, shows one inbound email for a while, which later vanishes.)

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot email - you can get excellent diagnostic logs from Mail.

- open connection doctor
- let the tool diagnose any issues
- if you have any warnings or errors - you can narrow them down in a new thread (post exactly how you have mail set up - what protocol, what mail server ports and settings are in use)
- if the lights are green, you can turn on diagnostic logging and get explicit details on how the Mac and the mail server are communicating.

Worst case, again, you can post a follow up question with exact details on what is failing and if it's intermittent or permanent. Free mail services generally are less reliable than a paid service, but even with free - you can often pinpoint a configuration change or error message that helps you know if the network is the problem, the mail server is the problem or you need a different client.